# Auto referral code generator in django

Tags: python, django

I am using userena in one of my  django project.i have decided that i will include a auto referral code generator option in my project.You know that ,to use userena,we have to create a extra django app and have to create a profile model.Thus,I have create a app namely **account** and my model is just like that,

```
import uuid
import base64
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from userena.utils import user_model_label 

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                           verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')  
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5)
```

in mention,this is the model **before** i added functionality for **auto referral code generator**.Then i have decided that,add some functionality to generate referral code for each user with the signup.Thats why i have added some functionality in my model,just like that...

```
import uuid
import base64
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile
from userena.utils import user_model_label 

class MyProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,unique=True,  
                        verbose_name=_('user'),related_name='my_profile')  
    favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),max_length=5)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/profile/show/%d' % self.id
    def generate_verification_code(self):
        return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes.encode("base64").rstrip())[:25]
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
        elif not self.verification_code:
            self.referral_code = self.generate_verification_code()
        return super(MyProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now an unique referral code is generating for each user after the signup.Thats fine,i don't face any problem with that,**but** since this  **MyProfile**(given above) model is related to the userena ,may be that's why(actually i am not sure) i am facing an error

```
'MyProfile' object has no attribute 'verification_code'
```

i am facing this above error ,**while** i am trying to **edit** my profile using **default userena profile editing option**.

i am mentioning it again, that this above error is occuring **while** i am trying to **edit** my profile using **default userena profile editing option**

i am posting the trackback also..

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://www.myproject.com/accounts/veer/edit/

```
Django Version: 1.5.5
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
'photo',
'userena',
'guardian',
'easy_thumbnails',
'accounts',
'cloudinary',
'paypal.standard.ipn',
'myprofile',
'watermarker',
'mail',
'stored_messages',
'rest_framework',
'endless_pagination')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args,        **callback_kwargs)
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/userena/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
28.         return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_guardian-1.1.1- py2.7.egg/guardian/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
106.             return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/userena/views.py" in profile_edit
711.             profile = form.save()
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/userena/forms.py" in save
241.         profile = super(EditProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/django/forms/models.py" in save
370.                              fail_message, commit, construct=False)
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/django/forms/models.py" in save_instance
87.         instance.save()
File "/codes/A/test/shutterstock/accounts/models.py" in save
23.             elif not self.verification_code:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/veer/edit/
Exception Value: 'MyProfile' object has no attribute 'verification_code'
```

now my question is that, **is there any other way to generate referral code with the signup or any other way**, using userena or is there any solution of my current problem** ?

Comment: could you post the traceback?

Comment: you can see , i have  edited my post and added the trackback @ skzryzg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
elif not self.verification_code:
```

should be:

```
elif not self.referral_code:
```

The following isn't a solution, but you also asked about alternatives.

If you only want to generate the code one time on signup(as opposed to generating it when it is empty or None), you can set a default value for the directly in the field:

```
referral_code = models.CharField(
    max_length=300, 
    blank=True, 
    null=True, 
    default = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(uuid.uuid1().bytes.encode("base64").rstrip())[:25])
```

And for `get_absolute_url` I highly suggest you use `reverse` with named urls rather than hard-coding the paths in.  For example, if you have a set of urls named 'profile' in which one was named "show" it would look something like this:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    return reverse("profile:show", args =(self.id,))
```

where your main urls.py would have an entry:

```
  url(r'^profile/', include(profile.urls), name = "profile"),
```

and profile.urls would have:

```
  url(r'^show/(?P<id>\d+)/$', view_name, name = "show),
```